# How to use a link instead of a button to call a pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion

Many people suggested to avoid using coldfusion UI tags such as cfwindow. Adam Cameron & Ray Camden created ColdFusion UI the Right Way at: http://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/ so people can have the alternatives.

I need a popup window and I don't mind if I don't use ColdFusion UI tag cfwindow. All I need is when user click on a link, a pop up window show up.
The example given my Ray Camden is using a button instead of a link. I need a link to open up a popup because I want to give my users details explanation about certain thing within my paragraph so I can't use a button.

How can I change the button into a link on the example below, is it possible? I've tried manipulating it but it wasn't successful.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--- I need to replace this button with a link, How can I do it? --->

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!--- button ends here --->


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>I have some content right here <cfoutput>#Now()#</cfoutput></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: can use click event on any element to open a modal. If bootstrap expects button for auto initialize (not sure that it even does), just initialize modal yourself within your own event handler. Simple example http://www.bootply.com/HzQXGTkgs5

Comment: Is there a reason why Bootstrap 3.0.3 is being used?

Answer (score 4):

Use below code. Just make sure to set properly `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes in your `anchor` tag

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</a>
```